# Do browsers respect realm string in WWW-Authenticate header from php?

Tags: php, http-headers, basic-authentication

I've create a basic authenticated page with php and set `WWW-Authenticated: Basic realm="My Realm"` header.
I've expected the message "My Realm" would be seen above the user input fields but only URL shows up as default setting.

I want have browsers to show a descent message on a specific page for users with IOS.
Though it is not secure at all but it's ok for now.

Usually I use apache on linux but this time, IIS on Windows2012R2 and it's private network.I thought php is reasonable to make authentication to work with one specific page.

setting `charset="UTF-8"` to header and
changing the realm word have no effect and I can't get any clues on search engine.
I've copied the following code from php.net as instruction for basic authentication , actual function works but only "My Realm" message is missing.

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
```

It would be better to show a message like "Enter your ID and Password" above the user input fields.

Comment: Are you sure that’s not an iOS issue? I tried a page protected with basic auth in Browserstack using an iPad Air, and that only showed “authentication required” in the credentials popup, and not the realm.

Comment: @04FS I've got same results that only shows URL in desktop and mobile browsers, so i guess it's not a IOS issue. Realm not only means having a message but it probably can as mentioned in [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate). I coudn't find in RFC docs.

Comment: Well you can’t do much more than send the correctly formatted header, if the client doesn’t want to play along, there isn’t much you can do about it.

Comment: @04FS so the answer is they don't respect it...

Comment: The [Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate#Browser_compatibility) table in MDN shows `?` for many browsers, including Safari.

Comment: @Barmar do you see it works on chrome desktop, mate?

Comment: I just tried one of our internal web pages with Chrome desktop, it doesn't show the realm in the password prompt, either.